# How to compile files with GLFW in Linux?

Tags: c, opengl, compiler-errors, glfw, undefined-reference

I am trying to run the code at the GLFW's official documentation here: http://www.glfw.org/documentation.html

I saved the code in `glfw-hello-world.c` and when I try to compile it,

```
clang `pkg-config --libs --static glfw3` glfw-hello-world.c
```

I get this error,

```
/tmp/glfw-hello-world-c0cd19.o: In function `main':
glfw-hello-world.c:(.text+0x9d): undefined reference to `glClear'
clang-6.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

GCC also gives me similar errors and I believe that my `-l`s are correct because `pkg-config` is handling that. What is that error and how can I compile it?

Comment: `glClear` is a OpenGL instruction. You have to link the OpenGL libraries too. With *gcc* it would be something like `-lGL -lGLU`

Comment: @Rabbid76 that worked. Thank you. Make it an answer please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> glfw-hello-world.c:(.text+0x9d): undefined reference to `glClear'

means that the function `glClear` was not defined.

[`glClear`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glClear.xhtml) is a OpenGL instruction. For the use of OpenGL hou have to linke the OpenGL libraries too.

For the use with [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/) you have to add the options `-lGL -lGLU`.